# Error in running django app

Tags: django, facebook, google-app-engine, django-nonrel

I'm using django-nonrel for creating an app which will be deployed on google appengine.I'm using django-social-auth which in turn uses python-oauth2 and now i'm getting this error.

```
ImproperlyConfigured at /
Error importing request processor module social_auth.context_processors: "No module named _io"
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://app.rajatsaxena.org:8000/
Django Version: 1.3
Exception Type: ImproperlyConfigured
Exception Value:    
Error importing request processor module social_auth.context_processors: "No module named _io"
Exception Location: /home/rajat/djangoapi/googapp/appengine2/fullauth/django/template/context.py in get_standard_processors, line 154
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python
Python Version: 2.7.1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
No module named _io
```

I had the error and downgrading to python 2.6 solved it for me.

If you run python 2.6, does the error still appear? I've had the same error and resolved it by downgrading python from 2.7 to 2.6, or specifically using 2.7 which currenlty is only available in the production environment.

If I were you I'd use 2.6 and wait a while until all the components are compatible with python 2.7.

Comment: I agree with you but how can i use python 2.5 on appengine,cuz recently appengine has launched support for python 2.7.When i deploy this app on appengine it gives 500 server error.

Comment: The default settings should give you 2.6 or 2.5. 2.6 worked for me locally and I could deploy it. If you make the change to 2.7 you must change a lot of things and follow a rather different procedure. If the code fails on production then I suggest you paste more code so that we can see more what's going on. python 2.6 worked for me with ubuntu, just do `sudo apt-get install python2.6` and then use python 2.6 as runtime locally. When you deploy to production there are different instructions for 2.6 and 2.7 so you probably won't confuse that. Also you can downgrade all the way to 2.5 if needed.